# Product name change: Managed VMs tags all to app-engine-flexible

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I work on App Engine Flexible. The product was renamed from "App Engine Managed VMs" to "App Engine Flexible", and we'd like to get the tag(s) updated.

There are 2 separate tags folks have been using:

- [google-managed-vm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-managed-vm)
- [managed-vm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/managed-vm)

All of the questions in both forums are related to App Engine Flexible.  Could we have the two existing tags combined, and then renamed to "app-engine-flexible"?

Comment: Why not create the new tag and synomize these old tags with the new one? That seems a better option then removing and renaming to be honest.

Comment: Which two are "both" forums? Also, calling Stack Overflow a forum is not really a good idea on Meta :).

Comment: Mea culpa.  I created the new tag, but I can't suggest a synonym until I have a score with the tag, which requires people asking questions with that tag.  It would be great if we could just merge them all, it's all for the same product :(